# How to find a filename that contains a given string

Tags: python

I'm attempting to look for a keyword of a text file within a directory then find out the whole name of the file using Python.

Let this keyword be `'file'`, but this text file in the directory is called `'newfile'`.

I'm trying to find out the name of the whole file in order to be able to open it.

Comment: Why python?  Ever heard of grep?

Answer (score 15):

```
import os

keyword = 'file'
for fname in os.listdir('directory/with/files'):
    if keyword in fname:
        print(fname, "has the keyword")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [**`fnmatch`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch). From the documentation:

> This example will print all file names in the current directory with the extension .txt:

```
import fnmatch
import os

for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, '*.txt'):
        print filename
```

From your example you would want `fnmatch(filename, '*file*')`.

e.g:

```
>>> from fnmatch import fnmatch
>>> fnmatch('newfile', '*file*')
True

>>> fnmatch('newfoal', '*file*')
False
```

Answer (score -1):

Using grep you can locate file containing the word you are looking for.

```
grep -r 'word' FOLDER
```

-r indicates grep to look for `'word'` in all the files of `FOLDER`